# GCM: Getting an already registered ID from GCM Server

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push notifications using Google's GCM for Android and I had a question about it. In the demo google provided, they have the program registering with the Play Services and getting a registration ID which is then sent to the GCM server. How can I obtain that registration ID that is sent to the server so that I can use it to send a message from my 3rd party server?

So far, to get the registration ID that my program generated, I just display it on the application itself but if one didn't have access to the device that's generating the registration ID, how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the ID on your server in some way. Whether this is in a plain text file or a database, I wrote my back-end in Python with Flask. You can associate with it a username and password,if you have user's register for an account. That way, you can store their device ID and send the respective messages to their device.